# How do I add requirements in kivy/iOS?

Tags: python, kivy

How do I add openssl as "requirements" in kivy/iOS? I don't use buildozer, at least consciously. I already did "./toolchain.py build openssl", but this didn't seem to have done the job.

(Longer version: I use garden.mapview, which in turn uses concurrent/futures and requests. When I run my app on Xcode I get "ImportError: No module named urllib3". I learned that to solve this I need to add openssl to requirements, but I don't know how to do it.)